# Is there any client side encryption for the messages published from my Java application to AWS SNS?

Tags: encryption, amazon-sns, aws-sts

I want to establish secure communication for the messages published to the AWS SNS topic. I want to encrypt all the messages through the certificates generated by XCA from my Java application. And also How to upload the servercert, serverkey to AWS SNS so that the encrypted messages can be decrypted at SNS. I want to establish data encryption in transit

Comment: maybe this could be relevant for you https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/encrypting-messages-published-to-amazon-sns-with-aws-kms/